# RSS feed - from a blog

Tags: blog, rss

I have multiple blogs within my SharePoint site. These blogs I wish to generate more views, with help from RSS on my SharePoint home page. How do I set up the feed containing the blog on my homepage? - I am not look on creating an external news news feed.

Any helps is appreciated, thank you.

Adam

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but of you use Office365 or SharePoint 2013, you could also solve this with a custom result source and a content by search webpart.

Answer (score 0):

Sad-face moment.

Unfortunately RSS feeds from inside your SharePoint cannot be displayed inside of SharePoint. (Seems silly, but stay with me.)

As MartijnE notes in the comment, there is a workaround to this using content search webpart instead of RSS feeds, gracefully explained here: http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2013/08/20/display-sharepoint-blogs-on-a-sharepoint-online-homepage-aspx/

In a nutshell, you activate Publishing Infrastructure, add the Content Query/Search webpart and then customize the Query to return the results of the blog postings.